# fetching duplicate tuples in Oracle using SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, plsqldeveloper

Here are the two table structures[image: Table 1][image: Table 2]

I have two tables where I am trying to fetch some duplicate records based on some condition like `where a.fname=b.fname and a.phone_no<>b.phone_no`

But also I need to include other column 'address' which is in table 2 and introduce the same condition for duplicate checking for address as well.

```
SELECT 
 "Fname"||' '||"Lname" AS "Customer_Name",
  COUNT(*) AS "Countof" 
FROM "S_CONTACT" A 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM "S_CONTACT" B 
  WHERE A."PHONE" != B."PHONE" 
    AND A."Fname" = B."Fname" 
    AND A."EMAIL"=B."EMAIL" 
    AND A."Lname"=B."Lname" 
    AND "DOB" IS NULL
) 
GROUP BY "Fname","Lname","EMAIL" 
HAVING count(*) >1;
```

The above sql gives me a list of customers with duplicate names and email.
But I do not know how to introduce the column address in this sql which is from different table t2

Comment: You claim to have two tables but your query only references one.  It would be helpful to know what results you want.

Comment: Hi,@GordonLinoff the above query is made for one table only in which its giving me count of duplicate entries but i also want to introduce another column in my sql "ADDRESS" which is from table 2.Table 1 and Table 2 are related with ROW_ID and PR_PER_ADDR_ID

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal: can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: @GordonLinoff query not working: 
SELECT "Fname"||' '||"Lname" AS "Customer_Name","ADDRESS",COUNT(*) AS "Countof" FROM "S_CONTACT" A,"S_ADDR_PER" C WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM 
"S_CONTACT" B, "S_ADDR_PER" D
WHERE A."PHONE" != B."PHONE" AND A."Fname" = B."Fname" AND A."EMAIL"=B."EMAIL" AND A."Lname"=B."Lname" AND "DOB" IS NULL AND 
C."ADDRESS"=D."ADDRESS" AND "S_CONTACT"."PR_PER_ADDR_ID"="S_ADDR_PER"."ROW_ID")
GROUP BY "Fname","Lname","EMAIL","ADDRESS" HAVING count(*) >1; 

conditions for sql:
fname -same
lname-same
email -same
phone -different ,address -same

Comment: @GordonLinoff  desired output:

Fname  Lname  EMAIL                 ADDRESS       Countof

Ashley Doug   ashley.doug@abc.com   13,louisiana  2
Chris  woakes chris.woakes@abc.com  14,louisiana  2

Comment: desired output:

Fname  Lname  EMAIL                           ADDRESS             Countof
Ashley Doug   ashley.doug@abc.com   13,louisiana            2
Chris  woakes chris.woakes@abc.com  14,louisiana            2

Comment: @GordonLinoff   need the count of duplicate tuples alongwith the fields  like name,email,address(from different table) and count

Comment: @GordonLinoff hey do you have answer for this?

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal: I still don't understand fully what you mean with "introduce the same condition for duplicate checking for address".

Comment: Need to fetch name,email, address which are duplicate by combining the above two tables along with count.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find duplicates in one table:

```
select c.fname, c.lname, c.email
from contacts c
group by c.fname, c.lname, c.email
having min(c.phone) <> max(c.phone);
```

If you want to count `null` as a different value, then use:

```
having min(c.phone) <> max(c.phone) or count(c.phone) <> count(*)
```

You can do the same thing on the second table:

```
select c.fname, c.lname, c.email
from second_table c
group by c.fname, c.lname, c.email
having min(c.address) <> max(c.address) or count(c.address) <> count(*)
```

If you need the results in the same result set, then use `union` or `union all` or some similar mechanism.

Comment: Hi Gordon,As you can see there are two tables and i want to fetch all the duplicate records along with its count. I have successfully done so for columns within the same table but my requirement is to pick up another column "ADDRESS" from table 2 as given in the image and compare it to check if its duplicate for the particular ROW_ID which is in relationship with PR_PER_ADDR_ID in table 1.I am having issues while picking up count for duplicate address when i am incorporating both.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: why are you using `having min(col)<>max(col)` instead of `having count(*)>1`. This won't work with `NULL` values, wouldn't it?

Comment: @wolφi . . . Because `count(*)` doesn't determine if the values are different.  But I see the values can be `NULL`, so I added the appropriate logic to the question.

Comment: But you `group by`, so `having` tests the number in your group, so `count` works correctly.

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal . . . Such explanations belong in the *question* not in the comments.

Comment: @Gordon what is the benefit of `min(c.phone) <> max(c.phone) or count(c.phone) <> count(*)` over `count(*) > 1` ?

Comment: @wolφi . . . The OP is trying to find people where the `phone` differs:  "I am trying to fetch some duplicate records based on some condition like where a.fname=b.fname and a.phone_no<>b.phone_no".

Comment: @Gordon: If he wants to find different phones, I'd normally use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT phone) > 1 `, that's still way simpler and clearer than min/max, isn't it?

Comment: @wolφi . . . Comparing the minimum and maximum is generally more efficient than using `count(distinct)`.  They do the same thing in this case, but `count(distinct)` is more expensive.

Comment: No, not in my experience, especially if there is an index involved. I just measured it on 70k rows. `count` costs 378, `min<>max` costs 492. If there is no usable index, both cost are equal.

Comment: @wolφi . . . It might depend on how many duplicates there are.  If there are only 2, there might be little difference.  As the number of duplicates grows, the intermediate structure for storing the individual values grows as well.  This is larger than the single value needed for `min()` and `max()`.